# How to control the width of buttons of ipywidgets.ToggleButtons

Tags: ipywidgets

A basic togglebutton looks like

```
widgets.ToggleButtons(
    options=['Slow', 'Regular', 'Fast'],
    description='Speed:',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    tooltips=['Description of slow', 'Description of regular', 'Description of fast'],
#     icons=['check'] * 3
)
```

Code comes from https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#ToggleButtons

But that produces rather large buttons for small text.

[image]

I have been playing with different options for layout, but that only affects the container of the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-style-attribute) says

> While the layout attribute only exposes layout-related CSS properties
> for the top-level DOM element of widgets, the style attribute is used
> to expose non-layout related styling attributes of widgets.
>
> However, the properties of the style attribute are specific to each
> widget type.

The solution lies in `style={"button_width": "50px"}`

Example

```
widgets.ToggleButtons(
    options=['A','B', 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC'],
    disabled=False,
    button_style='info', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    layout=widgets.Layout(width='auto'),
    style={"button_width": "auto"},
    #     icons=['check'] * 3
)

widgets.ToggleButtons(
    options=['A','B', 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC'],
    disabled=False,
    button_style='warning', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    layout=widgets.Layout(width='auto'),
    style={"button_width": "50px"},
    #     icons=['check'] * 3
)
```

[image]